# How to post-process IQueryable fields in code without losing the expression sent to DB?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

My asp.net core program exposes a GraphQL endpoint that is handled by HotChocolate. It naturally supports filtering/sorting that is translated to DB calls via `IQueryable` mechanism.

`UI --(graph ql)--> HotChocolate --(IQueryable)--> Logic --(IQueryable)--> DB`

Now in the logic layer I want to format some string in a property of the class. I can do that only in C# code. But if I materialize the `IQueryable` I have into an enumerable, I lose that translation. So I will always query for *all* items and will return an `IEnumerable` instead which will be manually filtered in-memory by HotChocolate:

`UI --(graph ql)--> HotChocolate ==(IEnumerable)==> Logic ==(all items)==> DB`

So how to "inject" the C# processing into `IQueryable` so that the filtering/sorting expression is preserved? I think I can do a visitor of sorts, but wouldn't that get translated into the DB call anyway? I assume there should be a straight-forward solution but I don't know who it's called?

Comment: A [mcve] may be helpful. The question is too generic for my brain to grasp.

Comment: `But if I materialize the IQueryable I have into an enumerable, I lose that translation.` Please show us an example of this, and how you came to this conclusion.

Comment: Mikhail, the example is really needed since HotChocolate materializes  IQueryable right before to build the response. It doesn't do that in the cycle of request Api -> your service -> DB. So it might be the case that you do that in your own code (by mistake or something like this).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that one way to achieve this would be to use AutoMapper's expression translation with `OnEnumerated()`: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource).html

```
_dbSet.UseAsDataSource().For<DTO>().OnEnumerated((dtos) => /* mutate */);
```

AutoMapper does the basic translation when mapping, but this is available in a separate package and isn't discoverable.

Answer (score 0):

There's some [discussion](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/issues/3043#issuecomment-783357059) regarding the similar issue on the hotchocolate github page.